# jquery target nth instance of class

Tags: jquery, json, target

I have a form with the id of `#jobForm`.
In `#jobForm`, I can have any number of `<div>`'s with the class `.jIN`

In `.jIN` I always have a single a class called `.allCharges`

I'm reading data from a json string returned from the web server.
There is a json array called `charges`.
in `charges`, there is a field called `block` that corresponds to the nth `.allCharges`.
I want to target and populate the correct `.allCharges` with `charges.chargesDesc`

I'm doing this:

```
<form id="jobForm">
  <div class="jIN">
    <div class="allCharges"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="jIN">
    <div class="allCharges"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="jIN">
    <div class="allCharges"></div>
  </div>
</form>

    var cl=json.charges.length;
    for(i=0;i<=cl-1;i++){
      var block=json.charges[i].block;
      $("#jobForm.jIN:eq("+block+") .allCharges").append( json.charges[i].chargeDesc ); 
    }
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: [nth child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) maybe?

Comment: Missing space in your selector? `$("#jobForm .jIN:eq("+block+") .allCharges").append( json.charges[i].chargeDesc );` after the ID and before the `.jIN` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

`$("#jobForm.jIN:eq("+block+") .allCharges")`

should read

`$("#jobForm .jIN").eq(block).find(".allCharges").append( json.charges[i].chargeDesc );`

You've mashed everything together.